# Azure Service Bus Queue improve read performance in .NET

Tags: .net, performance, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm working on the solution using Azure Service Bus Queue (Pricing tier is "Standard").

Currently, I have next reading mechanism:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);
        client.PrefetchCount = 20;

        client.OnMessageAsync(MessageHandler, new OnMessageOptions
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 10
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MessageHandler(BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        var queueReadElapsedTime = DateTime.UtcNow - message.EnqueuedTimeUtc;

        using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                var stringValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                await EventHandler.Handle(stringValue, queueReadElapsedTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to run performance tests where I had 20 applications which write to the queue and 1 which reads. After that, I measured the performance via Application Insights and I see that on average it takes about 0.7 - 1 second for a reading message from the queue. The internet connection is great so, I suppose almost all this time is a delay.

It's pretty slow in my case and I'd like to improve it.
Please take a look at the graph below (queueReadElapsedTime in the code sample):
[image: read messages performance measuring]

Is it possible to read messages from the queue in 0.5 seconds on average or less? And how if yes?

**UPDATE**

Messages arrived to the queue from the IoT Hub.
So my full flow is multiple devices send events to the IoT Hub then IoT Hub redirects (using routes) these events to the Service Bus Queue and then I read these events from the queue. As you can see, for measure queueReadElapsedTime used message.EnqueuedTimeUtc. I suppose, that this is a time when IoT Hub redirected event to the Service Bus Queue.

Comment: Share your benchmarking code. There are multiple parameters at the stake and latency is not the only one. How you create your queue clients, how you complete your messages, all matters. BTW, prefetch of 20 is a lot. Also, your single client is a single connection which you might be saturating quite quickly.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, thank you! 

I've updated the question.
About prefetch as 20, I found it in this article: https://lockmedown.com/everything-need-know-azure-service-bus-brokered-messaging-part-3/#prefetch
And, actually, before it, it was 5 and it worked even slower. About 1.6 seconds on average.

My business case is I have a big amount of devices which send a lot of concurrent events to the IoT Hub. And I need to be sure that every event (message) will be delivered to the server in a very short time (0.5 seconds, for example). Maybe you can suggest something different to Service Bus Queue?

Comment: In terms of throughput, it makes sense that increasing number of concurrent calls, you'd get a higher performance. But that's not the only thing at a play. Creating multiple clients would also improve the performance. In terms of latency, I don't know what could be done if you're on a standard tier. To get a dedicated latency, you might want to look into the option of Premium Tier.